# Find the volume enclosed by $\left({x^2\over a^2}+{y^2\over b^2}+{z^2\over c^2}\right)^2={x\over h}$

Tags: calculus

Find the volume enclosed by $\left({x^2\over a^2}+{y^2\over b^2}+{z^2\over c^2}\right)^2={x\over h}$, where a, b, c, h are real constants.

My attempt:
I use polar coordinates transformation and get
$$x=a r \sin\phi \cos\theta$$
$$y=b r \sin\phi \sin\theta$$
$$z=c r \cos\phi$$
The the original equation becomes $r^3={a\over h}\sin\phi \cos\theta$. so I get $r\in(0,1)$, $\phi\in(0,\pi)$, $\theta\in(0,\pi/2)$ and $(3\pi/2,2\pi)$.
and the volume will be: $\newcommand{\d}{\;\mathrm{d}}$
$$V=\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^\pi\int_0^1 abcr^2\sin\phi \d{r} \d\phi \d\theta+\int_{3\pi/2}^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\int_0^1 abcr^2 \sin\phi \d{r} \d\phi \d\theta$$

I'm not confident with my answer at all. Can anyone show me how to find the volume of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your volume is enclosed by the surface $r^3=\frac{a}{h}\sin{\phi}\cos{\theta}$, the upper limit for the integral over r should be $r=\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{h}\sin{\phi}\cos{\theta}}$. The volume should be

$$V=\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{h}\sin{\phi}\cos{\theta}}} \mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d}\phi \mathrm{d} \theta \ abcr^2 \sin \phi \\ + \int_{\frac{3\pi}{2}}^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{h}\sin{\phi}\cos{\theta}}} \mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d}\phi \mathrm{d} \theta \  abcr^2 \sin \phi$$

Comment: should I discuss whether $a\gt h$ since $r\in (0,1)$?